# Filter sprints by boards in Youtrack

Tags: youtrack

I have several different agile boards for different products we are creating. In the dropdown list of sprints I see all sprints for all agile boards. Is there a way to filter the sprints to show only the ones applicable for that board?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Fix version` field's bundle is shared between all the projects.
So when you create a board for project A you also see sprints (versions) you admit in another board created for project B.
You can check this assumption if refer to Administration-> Custom fields-> Fix version.
To fix this, create a copy of the bundle for one of the projects. Either from Agile board settings-> Create copy option in Board columns section OR from Projects -> Project A -> Fields -> Fix version -> Create independent copy.

Comment: Thank you! OP probably needs the `Sprints` field. On the `Custom Fields` admin page, look for values marked `multiple`. These are the fields susceptible to the problem. For us, that was `Sprints` and `Fix versions`. `Make independent copy` and deleting the copy's values cleaned up our mess.